# How is it possible to iterate over all subsets of a set represented by bits?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit

I was going though [this article](https://www.topcoder.com/community/competitive-programming/tutorials/a-bit-of-fun-fun-with-bits/) and it explains

> It is also possible to iterate over all the subsets of a particular subset (represented by a bit pattern), provided that you don’t mind visiting them in reverse order (if this is problematic, put them in a list as they’re generated, then walk the list backwards). The trick is similar to that for finding the lowest bit in a number. If we subtract 1 from a subset, then the lowest set element is cleared, and every lower element is set. However, we only want to set those lower elements that are in the superset. So the iteration step is just i = (i - 1) & superset.

I'm not able to understand it despite re-reading several times. Could someone explain with some example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we have some set represented as a bitmask, for example if we have the universe:

```
U = { A, B, C, D, E, F, G }
```

Then the consonants `S = { B, C, D, F, G }` could be represented as 0b1101110 (read from the right, the least significant bit corresponds to A), and we can iterate through subsets of this set with:

```
i = (i - 1) & S
```

Because subtracting 1 will borrow through any trailing zeroes and unset the lowest set bit, then `& S` clears up any bits that became set this way but are not in `S`. For example:

```
i0 = 0b1101110 (the whole S)
i1 = i0 - 1 & S = 0b1101110 - 1 & S = 0b1101101 & S = 0b1101100
```

So the next subset is `{ C, D, F, G }`, dropping B for now. Then the next is

```
i1 = 0b1101100
i2 = i1 - 1 & S = 0b1101100 - 1 & S = 0b1101011 & S = 0b1101010
```

Which represents `{ B, D, F, G }`.

By the way it can be done forwards without storing the whole thing in a list:

```
i = ((i | ~S) + 1) & S
```

Here we need an extra `| ~S` to set the "in between"-bits to make the `+ 1` carry through them, otherwise it's the same idea.